# Flutter audioplayer with second function at the same time

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

I am using an audioplayers package. I want to start an sound from an asset and at the same time i want to start second function. It is important to start both a the same time.

I tried to async, await on audioplayer.play(). I tried onCompleted but i am still getting some deley beetwen functions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can simply use

```
await Future.wait([
  startFunctionOne(),
  audioPlayer.play('assets/yourfile.mp3'),
  startFunctionTwo(),
]);
```

this take a List of function which run at once

Comment: I describe it wrong. I wanted to rum a function as soon as the music starts to play. But when i make it like. await audioplayer.play, someFunction() i have all the times different delays